# How to translate magento 2 customer login/registration url

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.2, translate

How I can translate customer login url?

`"customer/account/login/"` but example if I translate it to Estonian then it should look like this `"klient/kasutaja/sisselogimine"`. So if user changes website language it changes url.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can write a Custom Rewrite in

```
Dashboard -> Marketing -> SEO and Search-> URL Rewrites -> Add New Rewrite
```

Add Rewrite something like that

and then try again with  `http://yourdomain.com/klient/kasutaja/sisselogimine`

[image]